# What system is the planet at the end of Force Awakens in?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Do we know what system the planet Rey finds Luke on is in?

Comment: We do not know the system. We know the name of the planet ("Ahch-To", @MikeEdenfield) but it's NOT in any prior canon/legends. We DO know that it's near known space, since Han recognizes some nebulae nearby in BB-8th map portion (in novelization).

Comment: @DVK thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm sure someone can perform a Ramathorn Enhance on a scene in the movie and figure it out....

Answer (score 6):

### The planet is called "Ahch-To".  The name of the system hasn't been revealed, but since Tatooine is in the "Tatoo system", Dantooine is in the "Dantooine system", and Alderaan <del>is</del> was in the "Alderaan system", it might well be the "Ahch system" or "Ahch-To system"

From the leaked WGA script:

> EXT. AHCH-TO - DAY
>
> A pristine and mighty OCEAN.  Endless BLUE, dotted with random, beautiful, mountainous BLACK ROCK ISLANDS, dotted with countless GREEN TREES.
>
> The Millennium Falcon FLIES INTO VIEW, BANKS towards one of the ISLANDS.

...

> EXT. AHCH-TO ISLAND - STONE STRUCTURES - DAY
>
> Rey arrives at a clearing. Small, modest, primitive stone structures. But no one around. Rey walks past them, sees, senses no one.
>
> And then she stops. Feels something. She turns. Standing forty feet away from her, his back to us, is a MAN, in a CLOAK AND ROBE.
>
> Rey stares, knowing exactly who it is. But she just stares for what seems like forever. Until he finally TURNS, SLOWLY, to her. Pulls back his hood.
>
> IT IS LUKE SKYWALKER.

Lucasfilm's Pablo Hidalgo confirmed this [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/682745067392471040):

> So if you can see the WGA script, yes, the name of the planet from the end of the movie is there.

[image]

As does *Star Wars:  The Force Awakens:  The Visual Dictionary*, and - as seen in this picture - *Star Wars:  Rey's Story*:

[image]

> Those words were still echoing in Rey's head as she flew the *Falcon* high above Ahch-To...  Rey recognized the landscape from her dreams.

Comment: I'm not really sure why you need a picture of the book

Answer (score 3):

The tie-in novel [The Force Awakens: Rey's Story](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force_Awakens:_Rey's_Story) indicates that the planet is called **Ahch-To.**

> Those words were still echoing in Rey’s head as she flew the Falcon
>   high above Ahch-To. Rocky islands blanketed with beautiful green trees
>   jutted from the water that covered the planet.